# How to retrieve the value of an element within an element in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Project>
<Site Address="0" Connect="COM1,9600">
</Site>
</Project>
```

I am trying to get the value of 'Connect'

I have this code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xml);
var q = from x in doc.Root.Elements()
        where x.Name.LocalName == "Connect"
        select x;
ClientTB.Text = q.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

But when I run this I get the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If I change the where statement to:

```
        where x.Name.LocalName == "Site"
```

Then my text contains `<Site Address="0" Connect="COM1,9600"></Site>`

What do I need to do to get the value of Connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var q = from x in doc.Root.Elements()
        where x.Name.LocalName == "Site"
        select x.Attribute("Connect");
```

Alternative

```
 var q = from x in doc.Descendants("Site").Attributes("Connect")
         select x;
```